# what happened to syscalls.h?

Tags: c

I am testing some code examples of the K&R C book and it uses `#include "syscalls.h"` in one of its programs but the compiler complains about unable to find the file. What should I replace `syscalls.h` with? Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 10):

You should probably use `unistd.h` instead.
Check the man page for the call you're trying to make, as it is system dependent and can vary.

Answer (score 5):

Try including [unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html). I see in the documentation that the header has most of the system calls.

Answer (score 4):

Try including `sys/syscall.h`.

EDIT: note that the other answers are probably what you really want, as `unistd.h` has wrappers for most of the syscalls you want.

Answer (score 4):

`man syscall` will also be of interest for those doing:

```
syscall(SYS_ble)
```

manpages 4.04 says:

> ```
>    #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
>    #include <unistd.h>
>    #include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_xxx definitions */
>
>    long syscall(long number, ...);
> ```
>
> Symbolic constants for system call numbers can be found in the header file `<sys/syscall.h>`.

so in glibc you need:

- `unistd.h` for the `syscall` function
- `sys/syscall.h` for the `SYS_` macros

POSIX 7 [does not mention `syscall`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html), so it is just a [glibc extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/System-Calls.html#System-Calls).

It is also worth noting that the Ubuntu 16.04 package libc6-dev 2.23 has both:

```
/usr/include/syscall.h
/usr/include/sys/syscall.h
```

the first of which contains just:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
```

and so allows you to use in your code just:

```
#include <syscall.h>
```

But I can't find where that is documented at all, so I would advise you to just stick to the documented `#include <sys/syscall.h>`.